# Angular 2/5 - having issues getting numeric data from a select

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have a select control in my Angular app. The values are * (asterisk), 1, 2, ... 10.

My template looks like:

```html
<select multiple [ngModel]="search?.filter.value" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)" >
        <option *ngFor="let item of searchValues">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

... and in my valueChanged function I get a value when the user selects the * but undefined when they select a number. If I "force" the numbers to be string (i.e. change "1" to "1st") it works, but that's not what the client wants.

I've seen some posts suggesting this might be a bug in Angular, but I want to confirm that I'm not missing something before I go back to the client with some options.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[ngValue]`

```
<select multiple  [ngModel]="search?.filter.value" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)" >
        <option [ngValue]="item" *ngFor="let item of searchValues">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnagps?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)**